# Counting how many times the biggest number in a column appear in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

As per title, i want to know how to count how many times the biggest number of each column appears. This number is different for every column.

Comment: show an example

Comment: you mean the maximum of the column how many time it appears in the same column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following formula to count the largest number in column A:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,MAX(A:A))
```